# How do I read nested nodes in an xml file using Python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am writing a text adventure game, and I want to store the locations and the items the player can pick up at each location in an XML file. The game should read the XML file and create location objects that contain item objects as well as other attributes of that location.

I already tried out the following two tutorials by modifying their code to suit my needs: 
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/15/processing-xml-in-python-with-elementtree
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_xml_processing.htm

Below is the XML file:

```
<locations>
<location id="0">
    <descr>"You are in a hallway in the front part of the house. There is the front door to the north and rooms to the east and to the west. The hallway stretches back to the south."</descr>
    <exits>"N,W,S,E""</exits>
    <neighbors>"1,2,3,4"</neighbors>
    <item itemId="2">
        <name>"rusty key"</name>
        <description>this key looks old</description>
        <movable>true</movable>
        <edible>false</edible>
    </item> 
    <item itemId="1">
        <name>"hat"</name>
        <description>An old hat</description>
        <movable>true</movable>
        <edible>false</edible>
    </item>
</location>
<location itemId="1">
    <descr>"You are in the front yard of a brick house. The house is south of you and there is a road leading west and east."</descr>
    <exits>"S"</exits>
    <neighbors>"0"</neighbors>
    <item itemId="3">
        <name>"newspaper"</name>
        <description>today's newspaper</description>
        <movable>true</movable>
        <edible>false</edible>
    </item>    
</location>
```

Right now I am just trying to print out the various attributes. Once I know how to access them, putting them into a constructor to create the objects will be the easy part. Here is the code that I have so far. I can easily access all attributes of the location nodes, but I can only access the ID of each item. I don't know how to access the other attributes, such as the name, description, etc.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('gamefile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


for x in range(0,len(root)):
   print("description: "+root[x][0].text)
   print("exits: "+root[x][1].text)
   print("neighbors: "+root[x][2].text)
   for child in root[x]:
      if child.tag =='item':
         print(child.attrib)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for parsing XML relies on the tag order. Try writing it like this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('gamefile.xml')
locations = tree.getroot()

for location in locations:
    desc = location.findall('descr')
    exits = location.findall('exits')
    neighbors = location.findall('neighbors')
    print(desc[0].text)
    print(exits[0].text)
    print(neighbors[0].text)
    for item in location.findall('item'):
        for attr in item:
            print('{0}: {1}'.format(attr.tag, attr.text))
```

A better way is to serialize/deserialize between XML and python objects.